# Copy large file throttles after reaching 20GB on VMware guest

Tags: vmware, redhat-enterprise-linux

we've a VMware guest running RHEL7 experienced performance issue:
to copy a 'large' file (20GB plus), it takes 10+ seconds to have around 20GB data copied, then the copy process is slowed down a lot and the speed dropped to < 10 MB/s.

Copying or dd using smaller file size without problem.   I wonder if we need to do some OS tuning, or if it's issue with VMware.

Would anyone please help?
Thanks a lot.
/st wong

Comment: I bet that VM has 32GB RAM.

Comment: And at least one Snapshot.

Comment: Yes, it's 32GB RAM but not snapshot.  Will adding more RAM help in this case?  Thanks.

Comment: The first part of the copy goes to RAM, which is very fast. Then it goes to the real storage (even if this is virtualized). And the real speed of your storage is really bad - so bad, that I thought it might additionally suffer from the snapshot overhead.

Comment: Thanks for your advice.  Will do some more test to verify next week.